# How to emit a subscribe event in a nested object with Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a application in Angular that has a object that i want his acess in every component. This is the object:

```
export class CartModel {

  public items: ItemModel[] = [];
  public coupon?: Coupon;
  public payment?: PaymentOrderModel;
  public discount: number;
  public totalQty: number;
  public totalFee: number;
  public totalValue: number;

}
```

This object have a nested object called **payment** that can be null, this is the object:

```
export class PaymentOrderModel {

  public type: string = '';
  public method: string = '';
  public change: number = 0;
  public card?: CreditCardModel;
  public extra: any;

}
```

In my application i have a service called **CartService** that have this **CartModel** object.

This is the service line:

```
    private currentCartSubject: BehaviorSubject<CartModel> = new BehaviorSubject<CartModel>(new CartModel());
    
      constructor(
        private storageService: StorageService,
        private snackBarService: SnackBarService,
        private authService: AuthService,
        private companyService: CompanyService,
        private http: HttpClient
      ) {}

      getCurrentCart() {
        return this.currentCartSubject.asObservable();
      }
    
      get cart(): CartModel {
        return this.currentCartSubject.value;
      }
    
      set cart(cart: CartModel) {
        this.currentCartSubject.next(cart);
      }
```

This is the subscribe line:

```
this.cartService.getCurrentCart().subscribe(
  cart => {
    console.log("EMITED");
    this.cart = cart;
  }
);
```

In another component when a user click the button to choose his payment option i do this:

```
  selectCard(payment: any) {
    this.cartService.cart.payment = PaymentOrderModel.setPaymentOnDelivery(payment);
    this.facebookService.emitEvent('track', 'AddPaymentInfo');
    this.closeModal$.next(true);
  }
```

The problem is this line **this.cartService.cart.payment = PaymentOrderModel.setPaymentOnDelivery(payment);**, this is the function:

```
 static setPaymentOnDelivery(payment: any): PaymentOrderModel {
    return new PaymentOrderModel(
      'payment_on_delivery',
      payment.method,
      0,
      null as any,
      { name: payment.name, flag: payment.srcimg, brand: payment.brand }
    );
  }
```

This event is not fired and my subscribe don't recieve the object, but if i do this:

```
this.cartService.cart = new CartModel();
```

It fire, so the problem is the nested object, in some time ago i have a problem with this in a VueJs application and there they have this function for nested objects:

```
Vue.set(this.cart, 'payment', { name: payment.name, srcimg: payment.srcimg, brand: payment.brand });
```

How i can do this in Angular way?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding following line,

```
this.cartService.cart.payment = PaymentOrderModel.setPaymentOnDelivery(payment);
```

You're not calling the setter which is

```
set cart(cart: CartModel) {
    this.currentCartSubject.next(cart);
}
```

You are firstly calling getter `get cart()`, retrieving value and then changing the value of one of its field called `payment`.

A `BehaviorSubject` will not emit changes if you do not explicitly call `next()` method. In your case, you are just modifying the inner variable held by `BehaviorSubject` and this change will not be detected.

What I recommend is to clone a `CartModel`, override the field, and call setter directly.

```
this.cartService.cart = {
  ...this.cartService.cart, 
  payment: PaymentOrderModel.setPaymentOnDelivery(payment)
}
```

The three dots operator is called spread operator, you can find more details in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Your subscriber will receive data when observable will emit data,In your case you are emitting from `CartSerice` setter.

`this.cartService.cart.payment` - this line calling `CartService` getter

`this.cartService.cart = new CartModel();` -this line actually calls  `CartService` setter,thats why subscriber receiving data

So in order to receive data on setting payment,you can do something  like bellow

add inside `CartService`

```
set payment(payment: PaymentOrderModel) {
    this.currentCartSubject.value.payment = payment;
    this.currentCartSubject.next(this.currentCartSubject.value);
  }
```

And inside component replace

```
this.cartService.cart.payment = PaymentOrderModel.setPaymentOnDelivery(payment);
```

with

```
this.cartService.payment = PaymentOrderModel.setPaymentOnDelivery(payment);
```

modified `selectCard`

```
selectCard(payment: any) {
   this.cartService.payment = PaymentOrderModel.setPaymentOnDelivery(payment);
   this.facebookService.emitEvent('track', 'AddPaymentInfo');
   this.closeModal$.next(true);
}
```